# Expand/collapse entirely in CSS3

Tags: css

Back in the days when I was responsible for front-end development I could only achieve expand/collapse behavior through CSS plus javascript.
Is already possible to code a expand/collapse solution entirely in CSS3?

EDIT:
What I intend to do is something like [this](http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand.html) but here it is being used jQuery.

Comment: Can you do it by hovering or click only? If click only, this can't be done with CSS only.

Comment: Well, it *is* possible to do expand/collapse entirely in CSS. I've done it, but it also depends on how *complicated* of an expand/collapse feature you want. Without details of what exactly you're trying to do, we can't really help you.

Comment: @Mooseman Actually it depends...

Comment: @PeeHaa Do you mean `:active`?

Comment: It is possible, but to be doing it entirely via CSS more information is needed in the question. Like on which event, on clicking of which elements etc.

Comment: @Mooseman I mean it depends on what the markup looks like and what OP actually wants.

Answer (score 2):

As borrowed from [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) and slightly adjusted:

```
/* Default State */
div {
   background: green;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
   display: block
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxvf7/).

Advanced showcase with FadeIn here: (edited, didn't need keyframes as was pointed out in the comments!) http://jsfiddle.net/Dxvf7/2/

```
/* Default State */
 div.container > div {
    background: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}
/* Toggled State */
 div.container > input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS transitions? That code is overly complicated for the basic function it's doing...

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: @utxeee What did you mean?

Comment: Sorry Bram, it wasn't for you my last comment but for animuson.

Comment: Careful with the compatibility of `:checked`...

Comment: @animuson You are right, +1. I thought the `display` property would cause trouble, but using `height: 0` fixes that problem.

Comment: @Mooseman Let's just say that a browser that supports `transition` also supports `checked`. IE8 and less users will indeed need a JS (jQuery) fallback.